# How to get a Page's ComponentPresentations via OData?

Tags: c#, odata

This code:

```
  ContentDeliveryService cds = new ContentDeliveryService(...);
  Page itemPage = cds.Pages.Where(page => page.ItemId == itemId).Single();
```

Returns a page with zero ComponentPresentations (even though I know it has two).  Somehow, I need to do something like:

```
   cds.ComponentPresentations.Expand("ComponentPresentations");
```

so that the returned Page will have its ComponentPresentations field populated.

What is the right syntax for this?

Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this

```
var cp = (from item in service.ComponentPresentations.Expand("Component") select item)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(item => item.Component.Title == "YOUR COMPONENT TITLE")
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Forgive me, perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how that code sample helps.  In my case, I do not know the "item.Component.Title", because I do not know the identity of the component(s) belonging to the page. Given that I know nothing about the component presentations belonging to a page, how do I find them?  It seems like this is supposed to work by accessing the Page.ComponentPresentations field, but in these OData API's is it always null.  What is the workaround, how can I find the ComponentPresentations that belong to a Page, when I know nothing about the ComponentPresentations?